# How to restrict tweepy to give only geotagged tweets

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to get tweets from specific countries. I am using the tweepy api to fetch the tweets. Here is the code that I have so far -

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)
places = api.geo_search(query="India", granularity="country")
place_id = places[0].id
public_tweets = api.search(q="place:%s" % place_id)
for one in public_tweets:
        print(one.place)
```

And here is the result that I am getting for the above code snippet -

```
None
None
Place(_api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0x1033f7690>, country_code=u'IN', url=u'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/243cc16f6417a167.json', country=u'India', place_type=u'city', bounding_box=BoundingBox(_api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0x1033f7690>, type=u'Polygon', coordinates=[[[78.3897718, 17.3013989], [78.5404168, 17.3013989], [78.5404168, 17.4759], [78.3897718, 17.4759]]]), contained_within=[], full_name=u'Hyderabad, Andhra Pradesh', attributes={}, id=u'243cc16f6417a167', name=u'Hyderabad')
Place(_api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0x1033f7690>, country_code=u'IN', url=u'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/1b8680cd52a711cb.json', country=u'India', place_type=u'city', bounding_box=BoundingBox(_api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0x1033f7690>, type=u'Polygon', coordinates=[[[77.3734736, 12.9190365], [77.7393706, 12.9190365], [77.7393706, 13.2313813], [77.3734736, 13.2313813]]]), contained_within=[], full_name=u'Bengaluru, Karnataka', attributes={}, id=u'1b8680cd52a711cb', name=u'Bengaluru')
None
None
None
None
None
None
Place(_api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0x1033f7690>, country_code=u'IN', url=u'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/1dc2b546652c55dd.json', country=u'India', place_type=u'admin', bounding_box=BoundingBox(_api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0x1033f7690>, type=u'Polygon', coordinates=[[[73.8853747, 29.5438816], [76.9441213, 29.5438816], [76.9441213, 32.5763957], [73.8853747, 32.5763957]]]), contained_within=[], full_name=u'Punjab, India', attributes={}, id=u'1dc2b546652c55dd', name=u'Punjab')
Place(_api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0x1033f7690>, country_code=u'IN', url=u'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/1dc2b546652c55dd.json', country=u'India', place_type=u'admin', bounding_box=BoundingBox(_api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0x1033f7690>, type=u'Polygon', coordinates=[[[73.8853747, 29.5438816], [76.9441213, 29.5438816], [76.9441213, 32.5763957], [73.8853747, 32.5763957]]]), contained_within=[], full_name=u'Punjab, India', attributes={}, id=u'1dc2b546652c55dd', name=u'Punjab')
None
None
Place(_api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0x1033f7690>, country_code=u'IN', url=u'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/1b8680cd52a711cb.json', country=u'India', place_type=u'city', bounding_box=BoundingBox(_api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0x1033f7690>, type=u'Polygon', coordinates=[[[77.3734736, 12.9190365], [77.7393706, 12.9190365], [77.7393706, 13.2313813], [77.3734736, 13.2313813]]]), contained_within=[], full_name=u'Bengaluru, Karnataka', attributes={}, id=u'1b8680cd52a711cb', name=u'Bengaluru')
```

Most of the tweets are not geotagged. How do I make sure that only geotagged tweets show up in the results?

Answer (score 1):

You're approaching this the wrong way. Those two functions don't work like that.

Looking at the twitter documentations first:

1. [GET geo/search](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/geo/search), you're looking up the information correctly but as mentioned in the docs, it's not for GET search/tweets

> This is the recommended method to use find places that can be attached
>   to statuses/update.

2. [GET search/tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets), it's only used to lookup tweets that have the specific list of words (or single word) you're looking for. You *cannot* include geo_ids as part of the query unless you're looking for a tweet that literally contains it

> Returns a collection of relevant Tweets matching a specified query

3. geo_ids are used in [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search-by-place). If you scroll down and look at the example provided will give you an idea, or in statuses/update as mentioned in the docs under (1).

If you want geocoded tweets, you can retrict the location to obtain the tweets from using the `geocode` feature within `GET search/tweets`. This will give you all the tweets from that location, and once you obtain those only then you'll be able to filter geocoded tweets.

The filter must be done from your end, not Twitter's.

Answer (score 1):

I too ran into this issue where the actual geo codes of the tweets were always missing. However, you shouldn't need the actual geo codes of each tweet for what you are trying to do; rather, you can search for tweets within a specific geographic area, specifying coordinates and radius like so:

```
def wordsearch(word, max_tweets, lang, geocode, since, out):
    # Query for 100 tweets that have word in them and store it in a list 
    searched_tweets = [status for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, n=max_tweets, q=word, lang=lang,  geocode=geocode, since=since).items(max_tweets)]
    print("Number of Matches: %d\n" % len(searched_tweets))
    csvfile = open(out, 'a')
    csvWriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for t in searched_tweets:
        csvWriter.writerow([t.created_at, t.text.encode('utf-8'), t.author.screen_name, t.place, t.retweeted, t.retweet_count, (not t.retweeted and 'RT @' not in t.text)])
    csvfile.close()

wordsearch('dead', 100, "en", "37.9,91.8,1000mi", "2017-01-01",      "result.csv")
```